# Edit text after clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, append

I do not know how to do, so after onclick event change my code

```
<div id='1' onclick='edit()'>
    Tekst
</div>
```

on

```
<div id='1'>
    <form action='#' method=post>
        <input type='text' name='1' value='Tekst'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Of course div's id and input's name must be the same. I tried using append() but nothing happened, no errors and no results.

```
function edit(clicked_id)
    {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.size = "15";
        input.name = "text" + clicked_id;
        container.appendChild(input);
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to post your javascript

Comment: I've got some text. After click i want to edit this text.

Comment: You can have a look at [this plugin](http://jinplace.org/demo.html) for inline editing.
This is very nice, simple and this page has demos for implementation.

Comment: FYI - contenteditable="true" for required div will make it editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".editme").click(function(){
  $(this).html("<form><input type='text' name='" + $(this).attr("id") + "' value='" + $(this).text() + "' /></form>");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='1' class='editme'>
    Tekst
</div>
```

Comment: This is using jquery. I had started answering before you posted your javascript.

Comment: if you run the code snippet I posted you'll see it does work but requires jquery to be loaded. I currently don't have a pure javascript answer for you.

Comment: Youre solution is very simlpy and clear for me but does,t work on my page. I use jq too (this same version). Youre code copied directly on my code doesn't work and now question is "why"? Adnd what is wrong with this input? I can write inside only when i hold mousebutton on this.

Comment: @user3408192 you need to understand what is going on in Funk's script, it is bound to a click event, that means everytime you click on it, it regenerates itself. What are you actually looking to achieve here?